# How do Goliath or EventMachine switch context?

Tags: asynchronous, eventmachine, goliath

Assume I have an I/O-bounded operations. I do have a callbacks (or em-synchrony)

1. How does EM switch to proccess next request keeping previous one waiting for callback?
2. How does it keep Thread.current variables isolated?
3. How can I emulate long running jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. How does EM switch to proccess next request keeping previous one waiting for callback?**

In any reactor pattern there is a single thread of the execution. Meaning, only one thing can execute at a time. If the reactor is processing a request on that main thread, then no other request can intervene (cooperative scheduling). Now, the request can "relinquish" control either voluntarily (in EM, we have `EM.next_tick { # block }`), or by scheduling an operation in the future: a timer (`EM.add_timer { #block }`), or by making another IO operation!

For example, if you're using EM-Synchrony, then when you make an HTTP request (via em-http), then when the request is dispatched, the fiber is paused, and a callback is created for you under the hood.. When the request is finished, the callback is invoked by EventMachine, via an internal callback.. and control returns back to your request. For a more in-depth look:
http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/

**2. How does it keep Thread.current variables isolated?**

No magic. In Ruby, we have thread local variables: `Thread.current[:foo] = bar`. Similarly, Fiber's have the same semantics, although what sometimes catches people off-guard is that the same mechanism is used.. aka `Thread.current[:foo] = bar`.

See here: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/02/02/ruby-thread-locals-are-also-fiber-local/

**3. How can I emulate long running jobs?**

Best approach: move them outside of the reactor. This is true of *any* reactor system.

a) Create a job queue and push it to another process
b) EM does provide `EM.defer`, which spawns another thread.

Choose (a) whenever possible over (b).. you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Thanks, @igrigorik. In 3. I mean I have em-mongo and want to test that request doesn't block reactor. Maybe there is some common place where I can put 'sleep'?

Comment: You never want to use sleep in a reactor. Everything runs on the main thread (basically) and doing a sleep will pause everything.  The best way to test is to see if your server can handle multiple connections. You can also do something, if you're connecting to mysql, where you 'SELECT SLEEP(1)' which will cause MySQL to block, but that happens inside MySQL, not the reactor. Then, if you issue 10 queries, they should all return in 1 second, instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: 'SELECT SLEEP(1)' is exactly what I need. Thanks!